# Vaadin TableExport addon does not handle Label component directly

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

In my table I have a column defined as follows:

```
table.addContainerProperty("Skill", Label.class, null);
```

When I export this table using [TableExport](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/tableexport) addon

```
 Button excelExportButton = new Button("Export to Excel", click -> {
        ExcelExport excelExport;
        excelExport = new ExcelExport(table);
        excelExport.setReportTitle("Foo Bar");
        excelExport.setDisplayTotals(false);
        excelExport.export();
    });
```

I get `com.vaadin.ui.Label@6a3f610e` instead of text. How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used the TableExport addon but I have two solutions in my mind:

1. Use `String` as a property type: `table.addContainerProperty("Skill", String.class, null);`
2. Create your own extended `Label` and override the `toString()` method to return the value you want to see in exported excel sheets.

Comment: I cannot accept the first proposal, but second one did the trick. Thank you!